# How to separate the JSX part from render function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React.js and just use a little bit AngularJS, there is one question about React.js:

In AngularJS, the HTML part usually is separated from JS code as template, I like that way which make the code clean, I wonder **if there is a similar way I can do this in React, or just use a function to apply this.state/this.props to the HTML part?**

Thanks

Comment: If you structure most of your components to be stateless it pretty much is just the JSX and props.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/10/react-v0.14-rc1.html#stateless-function-components

Comment: And if you really want to separate the JSX out, it's just javascript, so you could always put that in a separate file and import it into the component. Not convinced it would be cleaner though.

Comment: I think you are fundamentally at odds with React if your goal is to seperate the contents of the `render` function from the bounds of the `render` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render` function is just a synchronous function. As long as the template has already been loaded by something you can absolutely do this.

```
//Some module that has loaded the HTML
import jsxStore from 'jsxStore';

class SillyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return jsxStore.getSillyComponent(this.props, this.state);
    }
}
```

The challenge here will be ensuring that the HTML is loaded by the time this call is made, since `render` doesn't accept asynchronous results. The HTML will have to be loaded **before** the component tries to do anything.

It should be noted that you are fighting React by doing this. The React idea of a component is a self-contained bundle of code and presentation. The goal is to keep the component in a single file, so that you can see the whole thing at once. This is different from frameworks like Angular **intentionally**. If you don't like this, React is not going to be a good fit for you.

Comment: Thanks, currently I am doing data visualization which require a lot of DOM manipulation(build complex DOM structure with tons of style), I thought the concept of component from React will help, but when come to reality, this really hard to achieve.

Comment: I don't think there is anything about data visualization and lots of DOM manipulations that is at odds with React. You will have to adapt your thinking though, because React is very different from Angular. If you try to use React like you use Angular, you are going to have a bad time. Even things that React is well-suited towards will be difficult if you try to use it like Angular.

Comment: thanks,  do you know if there is any library can do virtualDOM operation like in jQuery's css(), append() etcs?

Comment: @Kuan-using that type of functionality suggests that you're not "thinking React." Try writing a prototype that fully embraces React's patterns rather than trying to mix-in other platform and framework styles. React may be a good match (or not) for your needs and personal preferences.

Comment: @Kuan When you say `css()` and `append()`, I see React's `style` and just normal JSX declaration. `render` is called whenever `props` or `state` is updated, so as long as `render` describes the view properly, then all updates, like a newly appended child or an updated style, will be made automatically. If you have a specific use case, I can mock it up for you.